# How to handle posts from the 'covid-times' going forward?

Tags: discussion

We have a lot of questions, understandably, around covid.  Eg how to travel from x to y with restrictions, or do I have to quarantine when entering country c?

Post covid, whatever/whenever that is, we'll need to come up with a way of archiving or something these questions, as they'll be out of date/irrelevant. Thoughts? It'd be awful for someone to stumble upon an old question and think they need to pay say $3k to enter New Zealand managed isolation.

Comment: I think you might be wrong about *when* these questions are a problem. Post covid I imagine most rules would be fairly obviously no longer applicable. Whereas *right now*, while the pandemic continues, regulations in many places are changing so quickly that an answer on requirements to enter *country X* from this summer is likely to look perfectly plausible and yet be entirely wrong.

Comment: This is a problem I want to have. I tried bountying https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163541/is-there-really-no-way-for-australian-citizens-to-return-home-from-india-right-n to fix outdated information, but it didn't help. At least having the questions tagged with covid will make it easy to find such questions in the future and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

All these questions should be tagged with at least the [covid-19] tag and possibly with [event-based-effects], our general "this is something likely to expire some time soon" tag related to temporary closures and the like.

If you are very concerned that when the pandemic ends, people will think that a 2021 post about tests, vaccinations, certificates, or quarantines still applies, you can use a tag search to find these posts and edit answers to say "until [date], you had to ..." instead of "you have to ...". In the meantime you can edit them to make sure they have tags that will enable you to find them when that day comes.

Answer (score 2):

The site has a way to handle that kind of posts, lock for historical significance.

When you see a question that is really out of date, please flag and ask for that.

No need to wait till covid is gone, if it ever will be, judge each and every question you see.

Comment: The issue with that is average Bob who finds the question via google doesn't know what 'locked for historical significance' means, necessarily.  They don't know if the info is still right, or now wrong...

Comment: That goes for all information on internet and guidebooks.

Comment: @willeke true. So what can *we* do to improve on this shortcoming of all information on internet and guidebooks?

Comment: add the "post is related to a rapidly changing event" and/or a bolded/shaded box/etc notice to the question (and every answer?) giving a date-time or range when the Q&A was valid.